# react-native android build slow

Tags: react-native

Recently I updated my react-native project to latest version.

I noticed, that after tha update, running and debugging android version from Android Studio takes much longer time (~170seconds instead of ~30 seconds).

Also I noticed, that most expensive tasks are `generateDebugRFile`.

Could this tasks be optimized in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reasons, I had maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/guardian/android' } in my build.gradle file.

Removing it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 2):

npx react-native run-android --active-arch-only
[source](https://reactnative.dev/docs/build-speed)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).